Whatever decision he made, I would support it

Whatever decision he made, I would support it.

Is the sentence above conditional(subjunctive past) — "If he made any decision, I would support it."?
Or is the sentence in the past tense and the 'would' is in 'past future'?

As is so, so, so often the case, the meaning depends on context. It could be past tense, describing a behavior pattern that used to hold: back then, I used to support whatever decision he made. It could also be conditional, and even hypothetical: if he were to make a decision, I would support it.

All sentences with "if" are conditional, regardless of the grammar. Please note: the term subjunctive is no longer used. And anyway, it does not apply here.

Did you get that from here? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/563379/whatever-pronoun-conjunction-or-determiner

@Lambie I got the example sentence from a dictionary.

Well, maybe its presence on the other question came from that dictionary, too. That OP posted exactly the same sentence. You might want to tell us which dictionary you used.

By the most likely interpretation is the conditional one. But as Paul Tannenbaum says in a comment, with suitable context, it could be habitual in the past.
Note that in latter interpretation, would is not "future in the past", but habitual: it is equivalent to used to, but is a little more formal, and gets used in writing (especially narrative) more than in speech.

No, I don't think it means habitual at all. It's a weird conditional.

@Lambie What do you mean by 'weird' conditional?

@gomadeng I mean weird because it functions like my sentence 2). But isn't strictly speaking a conditional with if.

@Lambie: "It took me years to realize that my ex was an incessant contrarian. Whatever I said, she would disagree with." <-- This expresses a consistent behavioral pattern. Grammatically, it is similarly phrased as a conditional, because it's referring to a generalized pattern without referring to a concrete example; but the meaning here is not the same. A conditional expresses a possible occurrence (i.e. not proven to definitely happen, but stating a true fact in case it actually happens) whereas this expresses a recurring occurrence (i.e. definitely having happened repeatedly already)

@Flater Except here, it's Whatever decision he made, I would support it. Regardless of whether it is a "consistent behavioral pattern". If he made some decision, I would support it. is the same idea.

I think this would is the same as Every day he would catch the bus to school. Do you think that is conditional?

@Lambie: My example uses the exact same tenses, it's the exact same thing. But just to indulge you: "I've been such a fool. I stood by that man for years, through thick and thin. Whatever decision he made, I would support it. And now I find out that he's been mocking me behind my back for all these years."

Consider:

I would support any decision he made.

This is a general statement about hypothetical decisions (decisions he made in the past and decisions he might make in the future) and so "he makes" is backshifted to "he made".  That's the case for me, since I backshift there, but not every speaker does.
That sentence is synonymous with

Whatever decision he made, I would support it.

Any decision, at any time.  I support his decision-making. I have confidence in him as a decision-maker.
I'm answering the question as a speaker of AmE. There are differences between AmE and BrE with similar constructions, so I want to leave the door open to differences here. I'm not sure if there are any.
If it had referred to a particular past situation, I'd say "I would have supported...".

"Second conditional" for 2) as traditional grammars say:

"Whatever decision he made, I would support it".
whatever there is like if, for the grammar of the sentence.
Present: Whatever decision he makes, I will support it.
A less likely scenario: Whatever decision he made, I would support it.

"If he made any decision, I would support it."
If he makes any decision, I will support it.


If + simple past in the dependent clause (protasis) AND conditional in the main clause (apodosis).

If he went with us, we'd know.
If they sang, we'd hear them.

This form of conditional is spoken at a present time.
The one with whatever works like an if clause.
Past conditional tense (the "third conditional) here would be:
If he had made any decision, I would have supported it.

typo:  protasis.

I am not basing this on any grammar theory but my first interpretation of the sentence (as a native speaker fwiw) is of a one-time, non-habitual decision in the past.
"I didn't know who this guy was, but I just didn't care any more. Whatever decision he made, I would support it."

concise but persuasive
